# How to check if the value is given in google spread sheet cell

Tags: google-sheets

I want to check if the value is given in the cell, start time and end time.

It works fine now with the function like this:

```
=if(and(C9 > 0, B9 > 0),C9-B9, 0)
```

But instead of `0` I and to check the condition `not equal FALSE`.

```
=if(and(C9 != FALSE, B9 != FALSE),C9-B9, 0)
```

But the `!=` operator is not supported in google spread sheet.
How can I check if the value is not given in the cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "not equal" operator in Google Sheets is `<>`, not `!=`.

---

Alternatively, you could recast the formula as

```
=if(or(C9 = FALSE, B9 = FALSE), 0, C9-B9)
```

Answer (score -1):

In Google Sheets check equality like this:  `=a=b`

It will return true or false. You can extend it like this:

```
=if(a=b," result on true","result on false")
```

[sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ITDu3EoqfEgE-zqtlZKT8DOPw04RNh1xTIQ5uKi6NOA/edit?usp=sharing)